# maven-jaxb2-plugin episode of same project in Maven, possible?

Tags: maven-2, jaxb, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb-episode

I have a `basic.xsd` and two other `A.xsd` and `B.xsd`. `A.xsd` and `B.xsd` get converted into two different java packages, therefore I need two Maven executions of the same plugin.

Both XSDs refer to `basic.xsd` for some shared classes. If `basic.xsd` would come from a different project I could solve this problem really nicely through using `episodes` to prevent duplicate classes.

But how can I refer to the current project?

My first execution of the plugin is to generate only classes from `basic.xsd` into its own java namespace. After that the executios of `A.xsd` and `B.xsd` should know about the stuff generated from `basic.xsd`.

Can I somehow point to the generated episode of `basic.xsd`?

Somehting like

`<episodes><episodeFile>basicXSD.episode</episodeFile</episodes>` would be nice, but as far as I can see, I can only add dependencies... :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>first</id>
      ...
      <configuration>
        <episodeFile>${some.path}/first.episode</episodeFile>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>second</id>
      ...
      <configuration>
        <args>
          <arg>-b</arg>
          <arg>${some.path}/first.episode</arg>
        </args>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2006/09/separate_compil.html

Comment: This configuration does not generate an episode file for me.  Do I need to specify that the first should be an episode @franta-mejta.

Comment: @mattforni Episode file should be generated by default. Check your effective-pom if you have `<episode>` set to `true`. See https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Episodes for details.

Comment: I needed to specify that the execution was an episode, then everything worked fine.

Comment: @mattforni , could you please explain when you mean that "you have to specify that the execution was an episode" ? because I have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define two executions of the same plugin like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-whatever-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>execution1</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <configuration>
         ....
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>TheGoalYouNeed</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>process-sources</phase>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>execution2</id>
        <configuration>
           ...
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>TheGoalYouNeed</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>process-sources</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Yes, but the second and further executions do not use the episode generated from the first execution. You can only define to use episodes from other projects through the use of the `dependency` element. I can let multiple executions run without any problem, but then I get duplicate classes in different namespaces.

Comment: Have you checked that with the using of the episode?

Comment: Furthermore it sounds like you need to define different modules which contains the a.xsd, b.xsd and the base.xsd.