# maven-jaxb2-plugin episodes in same pom

Tags: maven, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have been looking around a lot regarding this issue. I found some suggestions, but I cannot make them work, so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

## Problem

I have inter-depending XSDs in the same maven project. I have commonA.xsd & commonB.xsd which have generic types and I have a specific.xsd which references those two.  The problem is that I cannot make the hierarchical generation work.

## My current pom.xml

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>base</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>commonA.xsd</include>
                    <include>commonB.xsd</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <generatePackage>common</generatePackage>
                <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc-common</generateDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>specific</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>specific.xsd</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <generatePackage>specific</generatePackage>
                <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc-specific</generateDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

## Attempted solutions

### Referencing the episode file

I found this page https://stackoverflow.com/a/11135186/284263 where it is proposed to reference the episode file.
`[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/path/to/xsd/COMMONA.XSD{122,60}].com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:/path/to/xsd/COMMONA.XSD; lineNumber: 122; columnNumber: 60; (the above customization is attached to the following location in the schema)`
This didn't work for me and it also feels a bit hacky.

### Create a bindings.xjb

I also looked into this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22559100/284263. I cannot find any 'real' examples anywhere, and I don't know if this is the correct approach anyway for my case.

### Referring to maven artifact

I found in the plugin's [documentation](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Configuration-Cheat-Sheet) that I can do something like this:

```xml
<episodes>
    <episode>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin-tests-po</artifactId>
        <!--  Version of the artifact. May be omitted.
        The plugin will then try to find the version using
        the dependencyManagement and dependencies of the project. -->
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </episode>
</episodes>
```

This is an external reference, as far as I understand. It doesn't work, because the artifact doesn't exist in the repo yet, e.g. when developing and having a SNAPSHOT version, or might be risky because it will refer an older version.

Any suggestions or corrections?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: You actually did not state the problem. You just said you have a specific schema referencing two common schemas. What is the problem?

Comment: Hey lexicore. The problem is that I cannot make the hierarchical generation work. I changed the question to reflect this.

Comment: By "hierarchical" you mean that the second execution should use classes from the first execution?

Comment: Yes. The 2 'commons' XSDs generate the common classes and the specific XSD uses them.