# maven-jaxb2-plugin reusing commons XSD within same project

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have a project which has a schema A and B, both within the same namespace. Both import schema C which also uses the same namespace. How can I generate JAXB classes for A and B to separate packages, while reusing the JAXB classes from C generated to a commons package?

I already know I should probably be using episodes and use the episode generated for schema C as bindings file for the separate executions of schema's A and B. Problem is I don't know how to refer to this generated episode file.

Here's an example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources-C</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <generatePackage>com.mymodel.commons</generatePackage>
                <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc-commons</generateDirectory>
                <schemas>
                    <schema><url>src/main/resources/xsd/mymodel/c.xsd</url></schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources-A</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <generatePackage>com.mymodel.a</generatePackage>
                <schemas>
                    <schema><url>src/main/resources/xsd/mymodel/a.xsd</url></schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources-B</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <generatePackage>com.mymodel.b</generatePackage>
                <schemas>
                    <schema><url>src/main/resources/xsd/mymodel/b.xsd</url></schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This causes an episode file to be created under:

```
target/generated-sources/xjc-commons/META-INF/sun-jaxb.episode
```

How do I refer to this episode/bindings file in executions for A and B? [Using Episodes](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Episodes) only mentions how to refer to an episode file from other jar dependencies (or I simply didn't understand it properly, which is more likely).

I've seen an older answer suggest to [pass it as a parameter `-b`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11135186/441662) to XJC, but that didn't seem to do anything for me. I still end up with the same class from C generated three times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin).

TL;DR here's a [test project](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin-support/tree/master/d/divide) which demonstrates how to do this.

This is possible, but is a bit hairy, so please bear with me.

If `a.xsd`, `b.xsd` and `c.xsd` are in the same namespace, `a.xsd` and `b.xsd` cannot *import* `c.xsd`, they can only *include* it. We want to generate each of the XSDs into its own package, say `test.a`, `test.b` and `test.c` and do it within the same single Maven project.

To do this we will need three separate executions of the `maven-jaxb2-plugin`, each configured with its own schema and target package. For example:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc-a</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatePackage>test.a</generatePackage>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/xjc-a</generateDirectory>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <includes>a.xsd</includes>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- xjc-b and xjc-c follow -->
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

[It is is important to use different target directories for separate executions](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Use-Separate-Target-Directories-for-Separate-Executions).

OK, this would create three target directories with three target packages. Next problem is that classes from `c.xsd` will generated in `test.a` and `test.b` which we want to avoid.

To achieve this, we have to tell XJC to use classes from `test.c` for types from `c.xsd`. This is actually what *episode* file is for. This file is normally generated under `META-INF\sun-jaxb.episode` and it contains bindings for all types in the processed schema. Here's an example generated for `c.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" if-exists="true" version="2.1">
  <bindings xmlns:tns="urn:test" if-exists="true" scd="x-schema::tns">
    <schemaBindings map="false">
      <package name="test.c"/>
    </schemaBindings>
    <bindings if-exists="true" scd="~tns:CType">
      <class ref="test.c.CType"/>
    </bindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Episode file is *actually* a normal bindings file. So you can directly use it in compilation:

```
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc-a</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatePackage>test.a</generatePackage>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/xjc-a</generateDirectory>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <includes>a.xsd</includes>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <bindings>
                            <binding>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}/xjc-c/META-INF</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>sun-jaxb.episode</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </fileset>
                            </binding>
                        </bindings>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

There is just one tiny problem left. Episode files generated by XJC also contain this fragment:

```
    <schemaBindings map="false">
      <!-- ... -->
    </schemaBindings>
```

It effectively says "do *not* generate code for schema in the given namespace". This would not be a problem if `a.xsd` or `b.xsd` would be in a different namespace. But since they are in the same namespace, this fragment will effectively turn off all code generation for `a.xsd` or `b.xsd`.

To work around this we can post-process the `sun-jaxb.episode` which was generated for `c.xsd`. This can be done with a simple XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="jaxb:schemaBindings"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT should be run after the code for `c.xsd`, but before the code for `a.xsd` and `b.xsd` is generated. This can be achieved by putting these executions into different phases (`generate-sources`, `process-sources`, `generate-resources`).

---

Below is the complete `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>divide</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>transform</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <transformationSets>
                        <transformationSet>
                            <dir>${project.build.directory}/xjc-c/META-INF</dir>
                            <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/xjc-c/META-INF</outputDir>
                            <includes>
                                <include>sun-jaxb.episode</include>
                            </includes>
                            <stylesheet>src/main/xslt/removeJaxbSchemaBindings.xslt</stylesheet>
                        </transformationSet>
                    </transformationSets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc-c</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <generatePackage>test.c</generatePackage>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/xjc-c</generateDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <includes>c.xsd</includes>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc-a</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <generatePackage>test.a</generatePackage>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/xjc-a</generateDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <includes>a.xsd</includes>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <bindings>
                                <binding>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/xjc-c/META-INF</directory>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>sun-jaxb.episode</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </binding>
                            </bindings>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc-b</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <generatePackage>test.b</generatePackage>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/xjc-b</generateDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <includes>b.xsd</includes>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <bindings>
                                <binding>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/xjc-c/META-INF</directory>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>sun-jaxb.episode</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </binding>
                            </bindings>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I did not expect this. I guess I'm trying to do something quite unconventional. Thank you so much for looking into this. I guess you had to play around with it a little bit too, considering the XSLT step :D

Comment: @BennyBottema It *is* unconventional. Conventional is one namespace - one package. You want one namespace - three packages. *If* `c.xsd` would have had its own namespace, it would have been much easier (no XSLT).

Comment: Yeah, thought as much. Unfortunately, I'm working with the constraints of a suite of legacy systems that are locked into this package pattern. Again, thank you so much for clearing this up!

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work if the entry schema is a WSDL which imports the respective XSD's. If I refer to the XSD's directly, this setup works. I'm not sure if I even need the WSDL's here, but is there a way around this?

Comment: @BennyBottema I don't have much experience with WSDLs. Probably yes, bindings+catalogs have much power, but hard to say without experimenting.

Comment: Just to add I think its awesome lexicore lurks stackoverflow and responds to these jaxb questions.. I'd give more votes but I only have one ;).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer and for providing the complete pom.xml. I had exactly the same problem (except of 11 (!) schemas instead of 2 including to a "common" schema). One hint: for the generateDirectory I had to use ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc-b instead of just ${project.build.directory}/xjc-b, so that the generated sources were also compiled.