# Maven-Jaxb2 Plugin Type references Are throwing Already Defined Errors

Tags: maven, xsd, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin, xjb

I'm new with Jaxb plugin to generate models. I have 2 xsd file , where one xsd is referencing type in other xsd

**common.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/schemas/common" 
    version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.example.com/schemas/common" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

        <xsd:complexType name="person">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="gender" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="dateOfBirth" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

**pupil.xsd** , this has refernce to person defined in **common.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
        elementFormDefault="qualified" 
        targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/schemas/pupil" version="1.0"
        xmlns:common="http://www.example.com/schemas/common"
        xmlns="http://www.example.com/schemas/pupil" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.example.com/schemas/common" schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/domain/schemas/common/common.xsd"/>

        <xsd:complexType name="student">
        <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="class" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="generralInfo" type="common:person"/>             
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

**catalog.cat** , try to use episode feature of plugin

> REWRITE_SYSTEM
>   "http://www.example.com/domain/schemas/common/common.xsd" "."

**pom.xml**, this my maven build configuration

```
<build>
    <defaultGoal>test</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <extension>true</extension>
          <catalog>src/main/resources/catalog.cat</catalog>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

while i run `mvn clean install`, I'm getting following
**Error**

> [ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [
>   http://www.example.com/domain/schemas/common/common.xsd{XXX,XX}].
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
>   http://www.example.com/domain/schemas/common/common.xsd; lineNumber:
>   XXX; columnNumber: XXX; 'person' is already defined

I tried to resolve this errors using various option mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394134/jaxb-property-value-is-already-defined-use-jaxbproperty-to-resolve-this), but it's help me. I think I'm doing something wrong in the binding configuration or pom configuration

Could some one point out what is wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out solution for my problem, there were so many thing i was doing wrong

1) Change

```
<xsd:include>  to <xsd:import>
```

2) Keep the name space same for `common.xsd`  and `pupil.xsd`

3) After these changes I followed , the steps from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50181542/1450401)

Here is sample [project](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin-support/tree/master/d/divide) from the author of plugin itself ,that address the same issue i was facing